# Stackoverflow Exception in Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, stack-overflow

I am trying to parse Json string into Java object using Gson library but i encountered StackoverflowException.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError 
    com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.checkNotPrimitive($Gson$Types.java:431)
    com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.access$000($Gson$Types.java:42)
    com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.($Gson$Types.java:540)
    com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.($Gson$Types.java:549)
    com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.($Gson$Types.java:542)
    com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.($Gson$Types.java:549)
    com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
```

**Json string:**

```
{"password":"ac@123","role":"normaluser","name":"Archana Chatterjee","username":"a.chatterjee","designation":"Teacher","id":"T_02","age":42}
```

**Parsing code:**

```
Entity entity = null;
entity = gson.fromJson(json, Staff.class);
```

**Java classes:**

```
public class Staff extends LoginEntity {
    Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();

    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;

    @SerializedName("designation")
    String designation;

    @SerializedName("role")
    String role;

    @SerializedName("age")
    int age;

}
public abstract class LoginEntity extends Entity {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();

    @SerializedName("username")
    String mailid;

    @SerializedName("password")
    String password;

}
Root class for all.
public abstract class Entity {
    Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();

    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;
}
```

I also found out [related error](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=440) in Gson2.2.2, but *i am using Gson 2.2.4* . So, just want to make sure Is this a error from my side or is it mentioned error in the link.

Comment: Does it happen even if you remove the logger member in the serialized classes?

Comment: It is working fine without `logger`. :) but i am unable to understand this behavior. It would be nice if you just explain this in an answer so that if someone faces the same issue then he doesnot have to dig into it for couple of hours like me.

Comment: I've not looked more into it than the page you linked to, but it would seem it tries to resolve the types of all members of the class, and fails with Logger for some reason. Without looking more closely into the Logger type, I can't tell you much more than that :) Hopefully someone else has a better grasp of the actual problem.

Comment: Why not Staff entity = null;
entity = gson.fromJson(json, Staff.class);

Comment: Your Staff class will also contain the properties from LoginEntity and Entity

Comment: It is because i was trying `entity = gson.fromJson(json, Entity.class);` to make the code open for all Entity types, as that didn't work so i specifically moved down to `Staff.class`. But your point makes sense if i am trying to parse into Staff then i will get Staff and hence type should be Staff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Excluding-Fields-From-Serialization-and-Deserialization):

> If a field is marked transient, (by default) it is ignored and not included in the JSON serialization or deserialization.
>
> ...
>
> By default, if you mark a field as transient, it will be excluded.  As
>   well, if a field is marked as "static" then by default it will be
>   excluded.

So the solution to your problem is simply to mark your `logger` as transient or static, for example:

```
transient Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
```

This way the variable will be excluded from serialization and deserialization, and you won't get that error.

UPDATE: [Looks like Gson now supports](https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-exclude-or-ignore-fields/) a `@Expose(serialize = boolean)` annotation to explicitly state what you want serialized and what you don't. However, for it to be respected you must call `.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` on your GsonBuilder and annotate every field that you want exposed.

Comment: This will work around the issue and I think you are right in that there is no point in serializing logger instance. In addition the there seems to be a genuine bug in Gson's code that tries to resolve generic type declarations. So it might make sense to still file a bug report so that the bug will get fixed, as it could affect other valid use cases.