# Convert Java object to Json in javax.ws.rs with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, jax-rs

I have a REST API that convert the response to **json format** successfully.

using: **javax.ws.rs**

```
return Response.ok().entity(travelRequisitionFormDTO).build();
```

However, if I try convert the same object to json using:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(travelRequisitionFormDTO);
```

**Here I get an exception**:

```
>     java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.checkNotPrimitive($Gson$Types.java:431)
```

Here is theQuestion

How do I convert a Java object to Json using Gson

Comment: Would be helpful if you share DTO.

Comment: can we have a look at your DTO please !

Comment: The DTO is a very big object (thousands of lines).

Comment: Is it possible to convert it to Json the same way that the services response converts it?

Comment: Is your DTO a simple POJO, or do you have some logging / other behaviour in there? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30673008/1538039

Comment: _the same way that the services response converts it_ ... This assumes that JAX-RS is using Gson? Do you **need** to use Gson, compared to Jackson for example?

Comment: The DTO is a POJO

Comment: I don't need to use Gson. Gson gives me an error, so I am hoping to use something else.   The REST endpoint response can convert it, so it must be possible.

Comment: Birdirectional relationship to the same class can often cause Stackoverflow during serialzaition.

Comment: -1 for a poor question because: 1) there was no mention or research if Gson is set as the default serializer (and I believe it is not); 2) no Gson version was mentioned (the HEAD `$Gson$Types:431` line differs); 3) insufficient stacktrace; 4) no debugging attempt trying at least to mark fields `transient`/`@Excluded` so that "bad" field could be caught, thus no relevant DTO was provided. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this, if you want to convert Simple POJO to Json String:--

```
// populate all field of travelRequisitionFormDTO

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(travelRequisitionFormDTO);
```

POM dependency:--

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try when I am back at my pc.